# Picking random unique items from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I want to pick 5 random colors from an array list like this one:

```
static final List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

static {
    colors.add(Color.RED);
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
}
```

It's pretty easy I can just do this...

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static Color getRandomColor() {
    return colors.get(random.nextInt(colors.size());
}
```

But what if I want to pick unique colors which aren't the same? So say I pick RED, how can I make sure to not pick RED again; preferably without removing it from the list, too.

**EDIT:**

I've found something that works:

```
Color generatedColor = Theme.randomColor();
for (int i = 0; i < pie.segments.size(); i++) {
    if (generatedColor == pie.segments.get(i).getColor()) {
        generatedColor = Theme.randomColor();
        return;
    }
}
this.color = generatedColor;
```

However someone suggested I just remove them all and re-add once I've finished generating them all, which method should I go for?

**EDIT 2:**

After shuffling, I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSnvP.png

Thanks! :)

Comment: Try `Collections.shuffle(List)` and pick first N colors.

Comment: Do you want to [Shuffle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm)?

Comment: I thought about that, but not as giving it an entire class -- I'll give it a go. Also what do you think of 'brute forcing' it? e.g I have an array of things that use the color, I generate a color check if it's been used and if it has regenerate?

Comment: I've never heard of a shuffle before? I'll look into it :) -- edit: I don't think a shuffle would be useful here

Comment: Shuffle is exactly what you want.  Shuffle it, then pick the first element, then the second, and so on.  If you don't want it to modify your array, make a copy, then shuffle.

Comment: So would I put the shuffle in the randomColor method? (shuffle each time the method is called)?

Comment: @felixangell No, make `List<Color> Theme.pickRandomColors(int numOfColorsToPick, List<Color> sourceColors)` method, which will be called once and which will have only single call to `Collections.shuffle()` inside it.

Comment: OHHH, that makes more sense

Comment: Okay, now it doesn't, lol.

Comment: Perhaps, your `sourceColors` list contains duplicated colors? ;)

Comment: Oh wow, I'm generally an idiot... somehow I added the same color to the list twice.

Comment: There were 9 colors, excluding the duplicated one so I still don't think the shuffle worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `remove` method, which return the object at the position and then remove it.

[`list.remove(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int))

Then your method becomes:

```
public static Color getRandomColor() {
    return colors.remove(random.nextInt(colors.size());
}
```

and when the list size is 0, reinsert all the colors.

Comment: I don't think it is that efficient to remove every element. I am guessing `Shuffle` mentioned by others is a better choice.

Comment: +1 While not as efficient as shuffle, this is the smallest change which would work.

Comment: Ended up with this solution, was the least hassle most of the errors I encountered were my own stupidity XD

Comment: I don't really know how Collections.shuffle(List) works, but if I may guess, every time you use this method the entire list is recombined using for example a swap between the current element to a random one.... this could be much inefficient than simply remove an element from a list

also, with this method, you re sure that if you have a list size N, after calling get Random Color in times, every colour has been returned exactly i times